# Does MVC require a different HttpConfiguration than WebApi for owin at startup?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, owin, asp.net-mvc-5

The project I'm working on uses MVC 5, web api 2, and owin to host a website and an api. I was wondering if there needs to be a separate config for the web api, that is not the `GlobalConfiguration`'s config. I am asking this question because when trying to get to a web page the app behaves like the request was to the api. Here is my startup and global.asax

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(app);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    }
}

public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config => 
        {
            AutofacConfig.Register(config);
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        });

        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new CustomerVoiceContextInitializer());
        CustomerVoiceContext db = new CustomerVoiceContext();
        db.Database.Initialize(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I spent some time switching over to using 2 separate configs. 1 for the MVC specific setup and another for the web api. So far so good. The `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` is being used for the MVC setup and I just newed up an `HttpConfiguration` for the api configuration. If anyone knows a better or more technically correct way of solving this issue please post.